# Extended Hooks In Codeigniter not firing when included

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to extend the functionality of the in built hooks by adding some hooks of my own.  The documentation on this is pretty scarce so Im posting it here in hopes one of you has done something similar.

I have added a MY_Hooks.php file under the application/core folder as follows

```
class MY_Hooks extends CI_Hooks {

public function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump( $this->hooks );
    echo "</pre>";

    //this works fine when placed right here
    $this->hooks["admin_start"] = function(){
      echo "Boosting";
    };
    // this doesnt work when i simply include the file from the theme directory
    if (file_exists(APPPATH.'themes/default/hooks.php'))
    {
        include(APPPATH.'themes/default/hooks.php');
    }
}
}
```

if you take a look at the comments you can see i have 1 snippet of code which works just fine.

```
 $this->hooks["admin_start"] = function(){
      echo "Boosting";
 };
```

and then in the next snippet, I am simply trying to include the same code from a themes directory that i have set up.  Which doesnt work. So im scratching my head as to why.

```
if (file_exists(APPPATH.'themes/default/hooks.php'))
    {
        include(APPPATH.'themes/default/hooks.php');
}
```

so its the same code just inside of an include file. Please tell me what Im missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What didn't work? The if or the include statement?

Comment: Yes, when i move the code into an include file it doesn't work.  But when it's as shown it works fine.  But it really needs to be included from the theme directory.  The IF is working fine. the $this->hooks parts seems to lose scope

Comment: Did you tried require_once?

Comment: the only way I can get it to work properly is by adding this to the `system/hooks` folder 

        `// Grab the theme "hooks" definition file.
        if (file_exists(APPPATH.'themes/default/hooks.php'))
        {
            include(APPPATH.'themes/default/hooks.php');
        }`  every time it hits `parent::__construct` inside this newly extended file it seems to kill everything

Comment: I assume you already set the hooks configuration? https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Comment: if you are talking about the hooks definition, thats what I'm trying to include from the theme folder.  There's a `hooks.php` file that lives inside my theme's folder that I'm trying to add.  I can't use the `config/hooks.php` file because it is outside of the theme's directory that currently is living at `application/themes`.  As it stands right now, it seems the only way for me to do this effectively is to totally overwrite the `CI_Hooks` class inside the core folder.  If I modify the `hooks.php` file that resides under `system/core/hooks.php` it works fine